# Laravel conflicts with Percona DB because of tables without Primary Keys

Tags: laravel, percona-xtradb-cluster

Laravel has 2 tables (migration, password_resets) that don't have PK and is causing problems with Percona DB. My current fix to this is to set Percona into:

```
  SET GLOBAL pxc_strict_mode=PERMISSIVE;
```

Error:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1105 Percona-XtraDB-Cluster prohibits use of DML command on a table (tt.password_resets) without an explicit primary key with pxc_strict_mode = ENFORCING or MASTER
```

Though I'm not sure if this is the best approach for this.

What should be the best approach to handling this scenario or what I'm doing is already acceptable?

Comment: Can't you just edit the migration and add a primary key?

Comment: considering that's a laravel default table, I'm not sure that's is such a good idea

Comment: It's the password reset table, go ahead and add a primary key. Won't affect the queries.

Comment: @IGP same for the migration table?

Comment: Should be the same.